# Does a single column CSV file have commas?

Tags: macos, csv

When i open my csv file in an excel it looks like this -
Header
Value1
Value2
Value3
Value4
Value5

I want to know whether this file actually has commas in it? I am aware that if i have multiple columns i will see the commas

Comment: You should not confuse CSV files with EXCEL files.   Excel is the default handler for CSV on Windows, possibly mac also - but that still makes it a text file.

Comment: Did you try opening the file in any text editor to see what it contains?

Comment: I did check in textEdit. and it does not show commas. It shows the header and values in the form of a vertical column. I wanted to make sure i am not missing anything here as its still a Comma Separated File

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

Given there is only one value in each record it would not have a comma given the spec.

> 4. Within the header and each record, there may be one or more
>    fields, separated by commas.  Each line should contain the same
>    number of fields throughout the file.  Spaces are considered part
>    of a field and should not be ignored.  The last field in the
>    record must not be followed by a comma.  For example:

Answer (score 3):

You can easily test that by opening the file in a text editor (e.g. Notepad on Windows). It will show the file as it is in text format, i.e., with commas present (if they are in the file). I would say that if it is single column, it won't have commas (but rather line breaks between the rows), but if you need to be sure just open it with a text editor.

Comment: Thanks foe the reply Schnitte! I already tried that and didn't see the commas. So just wanted to make sure if its actually not having the commas or I am missing something